# JavaScript AutoComplete w/ Trie

Tags: javascript, trie

I am having a hard time trying to implement an Autocomplete system in JS. I seen other languages on here, but I don't see a way how to implement the Trie using JS. My problem isn't a trie itself. It's more on how to return the words of the common prefix of the trie. Basically the suggestions. I feel like I am overthinking this final step, but I feel like I need to use dfs in some way to obtain the suggestive words. My logic isn't connecting in my head.

My Implementation:

```
class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.root = {};
    this.endOfWord = "*";
  }

  insert(word) {
    let node = this.root;
    for (const char of word) {
      if (!(char in node)) node[char] = {};
      node = node[char];
    }
    node[this.endOfWord] = word;
  }

  search(word) {
    let node = this.root;
    for (const char of word) {
      if (!(char in node)) return false;
      node = node[char];
    }
    return this.endOfWord in node;
  }

  startsWith(prefix) {
    let node = this.root;
    for (const char of prefix) {
      if (!(char in node)) return false;
      node = node[char];
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try writing a method that returns the first word that starts with a certain prefix (returns it as a string). Then one that returns the last such word. Then one that returns all such words (an array of strings).

Answer (score 0):

Your `startsWith` method would need to return an array. So when the prefix is not in the tree you should return an empty array.

If you *do* find the prefix, then start a depth-first search from that node in the tree, and yield all results you find there:

```
  startsWith(prefix) {
    let node = this.root;
    for (const char of prefix) {
      if (!(char in node)) return []; // No results
      node = node[char];
    }

    function * recur(prefix, node) {
      for (const char in node) {
        if (char == "*") {
          yield prefix;
        } else {
          yield * recur(prefix + char, node[char]);
        }
      }
    }
    
    return Array.from(recur(prefix, node));
  }
```